# Datalist selectIndex Change event not firing

Tags: c#, data-binding, datalist

Here is my `DataList`:

```
   <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CommandName="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <table>
                            <tr >
                                <td >
                                    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="img" ID="imgProduct" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("StudentPics") %>'></asp:ImageButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr >
                                <td >
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="idtxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Here is my code:

```
public partial class ClassTouch4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            datalistbind();

        }

    }


    protected void datalistbind()
    {
       //binding operation done !!!
    }

    protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataList1.SelectedItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I am putting `DataBind()` in `(!IsPostBack)` , I tried `CommandName="select"` but still it is not working. I also tried other solution but `selectedIndexChanged` is not firing. What I am missing?

Comment: Did you register the event using '+='

Comment: I tried it , but code not place it in code properly .. Could you please provide me Sample COde

Comment: Put into Page_Load : DataList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged);  Normally you can just type  'DataList1.SelectedIndexChanged +='   A message will appear to type "TAB key" and rest of the command will automatically be entered.